# why did I get a +1 but nothing evident?

Tags: support, voting

on my mobile I see I got a +1 yesterday.  I looked at the question / answer and saw nothing different than the day before.  ??? just curious.

Comment: Maybe the upvoter canceled their vote?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the post?

Comment: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/38682/what-exactly-does-some-mean-in-logic/38683#38683

Comment: @Eliran maybe that's it, I don't recall how many upvotes there were.  But wouldn't that show as a -1?

Comment: Do you mean +1 point, or 1 upvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For just one point, the most likely situation is: You spent 1 point on down-voting a question or answer.  The user or a mod deleted the item.  You were reimbursed the 1 point.

There could also be several changes rolled up into one: user "un-downvoted" one of your posts (+2), but you downvoted something (-1). Or other combinations.

As far as I can tell, there is no easy way to find out which question/answer was removed to cause this change.  You might see +6 as the net change, +5 for question upvote, +1 for deleting an answer you downvoted; I don't know of a way to trace back where the extra +1 came from.